# Virtual concatenation with arrays

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Suppose I have 3 double precision arrays `a1[]`, `a2[]`, `a3[]` each of length L1, L2, L3

Suppose I want to concatenate these arrays "virtually" That is I want to create a virtual 
array `a_virtual[]` such that `a_virtual = {a1[L1], a2[L2], a3[L3]}` logically, though physically  these arrays may not be contiguous to each other.

So if I want to access `a_virtual[5]` and `L1=2`,  `L2=3`, `L3=1` then `a3[0]` will be fetched. For accessing `a_virtual[0]`,  `a1[0]` will be fetched

How would I do this

- in C
- in C++ (how to do this with std::vectors in place of arrays would
  also be useful)
- in CUDA

I suspect if there is a way to do it, it would be the same for all the three environments, but there might be more efficient ways to do this within each environment depending on the
capabilities provided.

Comment: Why aren't the arrays be contiguous? Why can't they be? That makes this problem so much easier.

Comment: In the CUDA case you almost certainly don't want to do it, even if you could. A "flat" copy or "zip" operator on the host side as part of the host->device memory transfer is a much, much saner idea.

Comment: What is it about this problem that you can't figure out?

Comment: @talonmies what if the data is already on the GPU?  If the data are only accessed once as a single virtual array, but many times as separate arrays, then copying them to be contiguous may be worthless overhead.

Comment: @harrism: Well, in that scenario I supposed there might be a case for some sort of access device function which could serve up data from several sources uniformly, but it certainly won't perform all that well, I would guess. But there would be an equally valid case for designing the code so that the data never got separated into non contiguous memory the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution in C, using linked-list and (tail) recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dblarr {
    double *data;
    size_t len;
    struct dblarr *next;
};

double *fetch(const struct dblarr *arr, size_t index) {
    if (arr == NULL) return NULL;
    if (index < arr->len) return arr->data + index;
    return fetch(arr->next, index - arr->len);
}

int main(void) {
    double a1[2] = {1, 2};
    double a2[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    double a3[1] = {1};
    struct dblarr x1, x2, x3;

    x1.data = a1; x1.len = sizeof a1 / sizeof *a1; x1.next = &x2;
    x2.data = a2; x2.len = sizeof a2 / sizeof *a2; x2.next = &x3;
    x3.data = a3; x3.len = sizeof a3 / sizeof *a3; x3.next = NULL;

    printf("before %f\n", *fetch(&x1, 5));
    *fetch(&x1, 5) = 0.42;
    printf(" after %f\n", *fetch(&x1, 5));

    return 0;
}
```

You can "see the code running" at http://ideone.com/mY0ix.

Comment: After 1 hour drive, I thought of an improvement: the `fetch` function should return a pointer to the correct value (or NULL), so that you can both read and write in the array. *Answer edited*

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays need not be contiguous, then one way to do it is to convert a single index into two indices, one for an array of pointers to the real arrays, and another for the array that has the desired element.

To do this, you would create an array of pointers to those arrays:

```
double** arrays = {a1, a2, a3};
```

then an array of their lengths:

```
int arraysizes = { sizeof(a1) / sizeof(*a1), sizeof(a2) / sizeof(*a2), sizeof(a3) / sizeof(*a3) };
```

Then, given an index `n`, you can calculate the two indices for `arrays` by doing

```
int i1 = 0, j = 0;

while (n - arraysizes[j] >= 0)
    n -= arraysizes[j++], ++i1;
```

And you can then index the array of pointers like this to get the actual element:

```
arrays[n][i2]
```

You could also create a wrapper class to do this arithmetic with a built in `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following? It's pretty hard-coded and not the best/ cleanest code, but maybe you can generalize this logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void logicalConcat(vector<int>& a1, vector<int>& a2, vector<int>& a3, int k) {

    if(k > a1.size() - 1)
        k -= a1.size();
    else { 
        cout << a1[k] << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(k > a2.size() - 1)
        k -= a1.size();
    else {
        cout << a2[k] << endl;
        return;
    } 

    cout << a3[k] << endl;
}
```

Here k would be the index of the the virtual concatenation you want. We're not concatenating anything, just iterating over the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the others provide an answer for a basic C implementation.

Here is some sample code for a general-purpose c++ implementation of a class which creates virtual concatenated arrays without copying any of the array elements.  Once created, the virtual array can be indexed like an ordinary vector (to be read or written to):

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

class VirtualArray {
public:
    multimap<int,double*> startIndices;  // reverse map of starting index to its sub array
    int size;

    VirtualArray() : size(0) {}

    double & operator[](int i) {
        // find proper subarray in log(n) time
        multimap<int,double*>::iterator iter = --startIndices.upper_bound(i);
        double *subarray = iter->second;
        int startIndex = iter->first;

        // index into subarray
        return subarray[i-startIndex];
    }

    void addArray(double* array, int length) {
        startIndices.insert(make_pair(size, array));
        size += length;
    }

    void addVector(vector<double> & vec) {
        startIndices.insert(make_pair(size, vec.data()));
        size += vec.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    double a1[3], a2[4], a3[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int L1 = 3, L2 = 4, L3 = 6;

    vector<double> a3vec;
    a3vec.assign(a3,a3+6);

    VirtualArray vArray;
    vArray.addArray(a1,L1);
    vArray.addArray(a2,L2);
    vArray.addVector(a3vec);

    cout << vArray[10];
    return 0;
}
```